# Induction heating

Tags: power-electronics, impedance, impedance-matching, induction

I was reading the working principles of induction heating and I think I understand the basics. Out of curiosity, I searched the Internet for a schematic and found one. However, the thing that confuses me are the inductors beside the work coil. I don't get their purpose.

They're obviously not there for impedance matching cause the tank circuit is already matched w.r.t to the resonant frequency of 133kHz given the work coil is at 0.47uH and capacitor bank is at 3.33uF. Or are they?

[image: schematic diagram]

([Image source: Kaizer Power Electronics - Royer induction heater](http://kaizerpowerelectronics.dk/general-electronics/royer-induction-heater/))

Comment: Saturable reactors to effect gate switching is my guess with a quick glance, but haven't studied the circuit in detail.

Comment: Sometimes the designer uses RFC radio-frequency-chokes, to allow DC to the tank + amplifier, yet keep the high-power RF energy out of the VDD network.

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation. You guys really helped me develop a better understanding. Thanks once again. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Induction heating power supplies

With a series tuned load, R and L and C all in series, it is normal and expected to drive the resonant circuit with a voltage source.

With a parallel tank circuit such as yours, it is normal to drive the resonant circuit with a current source.

Inductors L1 and L2 act as (pseudo) current sources during part of the cycle. Energy is stored in the magnetic field when transistor is on, and then energy is released (current source) when transistor is turned off.

The inductors also set the maximum current at the operating frequency. By virtue of how long the transistor is on and energy is stored.  This will set your power level since your circuit does not have an input to control power.

Get a simulator and see what happens as you change the value of the inductors. Parallel tank (resonant) circuits don't much like being driven from voltage sources. Nor do the transistors.

EDIT 1 :  Your question in your comment, regarding how inductor current can be higher than you expected. .

For your particular circuit, imagine it as two (2) boost converters working together (alternating). Current in the inductors L1 and L2 will become continuous. Go investigate boost converter where choke current becomes continuous.

As I mentioned earlier, use a simulator (such as LT Spice, free). And many things will become much clearer to you.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it with such clarity. I know it can be frustrating to explain such easy topics to newbies. So, thank you once again. And one more thing. The inductive impedance of these chokes, according to the impedance formula, gives a current of less than 1A at 133kHz. However, the chokes are rated at 13A and the practical implementation on the website shows more than 8A passing through these chokes. Can you explain this to me or guide me to a reference book or source so that I can get a better understanding.

Comment: Oh now I get it. Thank you. You have been very helpful.